# Order publishing/reading book series

Tags: character-development

I am writing a series of 9 stories.

The  main characters of all the stories are long time friends. The timelines for the stories overlap. Many of the characters will have parts in all the stories.

- Character V's story starts in June of year 1...their story will last for 2+ years before concluding. V's actions will directly impact all the stories.
- Character J's story starts in August of year 1. J's story will be over after about 3 months.
- Character B's story starts in October of year 1 and be over in under 3 months .
- Character F's story will start in December of year 1 and be over in about 3 months.
- Character M's story will start in December of year 1 and be over in about 6 months.

The other four stories follow similar timelines.

Since V's story starts first should their story be first or should it be last as not to give too much away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a *series*, typically the protagonists or the setting or some characters are the same – so they are part of the same fictional universe – but each book tells a separate, standalone story that can be read on it's own, with either no overarching storyline or only one that develops slowly and isn't driving the main plot of each book. A series is open-ended and can continue indefinitely.

In a *multivolume work* there is one main story arc that develops over several books. None of the books can be read on their own because significant parts of the story will be missing. A multivolume work consists of a predifined number of books and ends after the last one.

If you write a series, make sure each book stands on its own and none of the others must be read to understand an individual book from the series and the order of reading them is mostly irrelevant. Think of the *Reacher* series by Lee Child.

If you write a series, make sure you don't give away so much of the plot of the other books that reading them will feel like "I've read this before".

If you write a multivolume work, they may or may not have a specific order of reading them. If there is some kind of progress or revelation occuring over the books, they have a specific reading order. If they narrate the same events from the contradicting perspectives of different characters and none of the views is eventually revealed as the correct one but they remain equivalent, the reading order is irrelevant.

You decide what kind of story you tell. Is it a progression from some beginning toward some end? Then you may have to leave out certain information that is revealed in later books from the earlier ones. Or is it achronological and each volume stands "beside" all others? Then make sure that the overlapping information is either small (so as not to bore the reader) or conflicting (so as to intrigue the reader and irritate them) or new (that is, every viewpoint provides a different part of the puzzle and you need them all to understand the whole).

Comment: I would argue against your idea of the books in a series. Although there are some books in a series that you can read on their own, with no prior knowledge of the series or any prior books, you would have no idea what's happening. The read wouldn't flow nearly as smoothly as it would otherwise. I would also say that they are not their own 'separate, standalone story', but that they contribute to the main story of the series, because generally, a single book in a series cannot be read and understood (unless it's the first book).

Comment: @SlightlyPsychotic Then we have a different definition of *series*. *Reacher* is a series. Or the *Famous Five* are. You can read all of the books in these series in any order you want. If there is a "main story" that develops over several books, it is not a series in my definition but a multivolume work. A multivolume work with a "main story" cannot be open ended, because that "main story" will eventually reach its end.